# During normalization of data, can I add my own attributes?

Tags: mysql, database

Can we add our own attributed to the main table during the normalization process.
For example, we have

```
custid, custname, invoice_date, invoice amount, prod_code, prod_description.
```

Can I add invoice_ID to the table ?

Comment: Its your schema. You can do whatever you like.

Comment: it is my assignment so the given attributes of the table is
cust_id, cust_name, invoice_date, invoice amount, prod_code, prod_description. i am finding it difficult to normalize it to 3NF 
what i did is 
Table Customer (CUST_CODE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_AREACODE, CUST_PHONE)
Primary key(CUST_CODE);

Table Product (PROD_CODE, PROD_DESCRIPT)
Primary key(PROD_CODE);
Table Invoice (CUST_CODE, PROD_CODE, INV_DATE, INV_AMOUNT)
Primary Key (CUST_CODE, PROD_CODE, INV_DATE)
Foreign Key(CUST_CODE) References Table Customer
Foreign Key(PROD_CODE) References Table Product;

do think this is correc

Comment: That's not appropriate for a comment. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have left out a lot of key details making this is a very poor question. Assuming you have have the correct permission/role in any DBMS you can alter any table attributes. The normalisation processes normally comes after you have a draft version of what information you want to represent in each table and then follow the steps of the normalisation process.

http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

(Also some advice, you haven't posed any of your DB or even what attributes belong to what table above, in which case if all of the attributes you have listed above belong to the single table this breaks the second/third normal form rule)

Answer (score 0):

An example of a normalised environment:

```
customers
customer_id*, customer_name

invoices
invoice_id*,invoice_date, customer_id,invoice amount

products
product_id*,product_code, product_description

invoice_detail
invoice_id*,product_id*,quantity

* = (component of) primary key
```

This assumes that there is a 1:1 relationship between orders and invoices, and that invoices are generated on the date an order is placed.